# How to generate Oauth signature in ios(Objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had stuck in this problem  from last 5-6 days, I want to get user timeline feeds from twitter user_timeline api I'm getting error code 32 with message could not authenticate you. I have tried alot but with no success. Please help me to get out from this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)getNewTimelineoFUser: (NSString *)userId{
NSString *oauth_timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[NSDate.date timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSString *oauth_nonce =  [self genRandString];
NSString *oauth_consumer_key = @"**************";
NSString *oauth_token = @"*****************************************";
NSString *oauth_signature_method = @"HMAC-SHA1";
NSString *oauth_version = @"1.0";
NSMutableDictionary *standardParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[standardParameters setValue:@"true" forKey:@"include_entities"];
[standardParameters setValue:oauth_consumer_key     forKey:@"oauth_consumer_key"];
[standardParameters setValue:oauth_nonce            forKey:@"oauth_nonce"];
[standardParameters setValue:oauth_signature_method forKey:@"oauth_signature_method"];
[standardParameters setValue:oauth_timestamp        forKey:@"oauth_timestamp"];
[standardParameters setValue:oauth_version          forKey:@"oauth_version"];
[standardParameters setValue:oauth_token    forKey:@"oauth_token"];

NSString *parametersString = @"";

parametersString = [parametersString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",[self encodingString:@"include_entities"],[self encodingString:@"true"]]];
parametersString = [parametersString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",[self encodingString:@"oauth_consumer_key"],[self encodingString:oauth_consumer_key]]];
parametersString = [parametersString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",[self encodingString:@"oauth_nonce"],[self encodingString:oauth_nonce]]];
parametersString = [parametersString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",[self encodingString:@"oauth_signature_method"],[self encodingString:oauth_signature_method]]];
parametersString = [parametersString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",[self encodingString:@"oauth_timestamp"],[self encodingString:oauth_timestamp]]];
parametersString = [parametersString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",[self encodingString:@"oauth_token"],[self encodingString:oauth_token]]];
parametersString = [parametersString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",[self encodingString:@"oauth_version"],[self encodingString:oauth_version]]];

NSLog(@"parameterString %@",parametersString);

/* OAUTH SIGNATURE */
NSString *request_url =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=TomCruise"] ;//@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
NSString *oauth_consumer_secret = @"******************";
NSString *oauth_token_secret = @"****************************************";
NSString *baseString = [@"GET" stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@&%@", [self encodingString:request_url], [self encodingString:parametersString] ];
// append oauth token secret to consumer secret

NSLog(@"baseString %@",baseString);
NSString *secretString = [[self encodingString:oauth_consumer_secret] stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@",[self encodingString:oauth_token_secret]];

NSLog(@"signingKey %@", secretString);

NSString *oauth_signature =  [self hmacsha1:baseString secret:secretString];
standardParameters[@"oauth_signature"] = [self encodingString:oauth_signature];
```

NSLog(@"oath Signature new %@",oauth_signature);

```
/* CREATE HEADER */
NSMutableArray *parameterPairs = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *name in standardParameters)
{
    if(![name isEqualToString:@"include_entities"]){
        NSString *aPair = [[self encodingString:name] stringByAppendingFormat:@"=\"%@\"", [self encodingString:standardParameters[name]] ];
        [parameterPairs addObject:aPair];
    }
}

NSString *oAuthHeader = [@"OAuth " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [parameterPairs componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];

NSLog(@"oauth Header %@",oAuthHeader);

NSMutableDictionary *dicParam = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dicParam setValue:userId forKey:@"userid"];
[dicParam setValue:@(5) forKey:@"count"];
[dicParam setValue:@"TomCruise" forKey:@"screen_name"];



NSLog(@"request url %@", request_url);
[self WebServiceAPIForString:request_url andparameter:dicParam andMethod:@"GET" authorizationToken:oAuthHeader];
```

}

```
- (NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)data secret:(NSString *)key {

const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

NSString *hash =  [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

return hash;
```

}

```
- (NSString *)encodingString:(NSString *)str
```

{

```
//return  str.utf8AndURLEncode;
NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
const unsigned char * source = (const unsigned char *)[str UTF8String];
int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
    const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
    if (thisChar == ' '){
        [output appendString:@"+"];
    } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' ||
               (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
               (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
               (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
    } else {
        [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
    }
}
return output;
```

}

```
-(NSString *) genRandString {
//fixing length of 4 chars
NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 4];
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
}

return randomString;
```

}

```
-(NSDictionary *)WebServiceAPIForString:(NSString *)urlforwebService andparameter:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameter andMethod:(NSString*)aMethod authorizationToken:(NSString*)authToken{

NSDictionary *allDataDictionary;
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                           @"Authorization": authToken
                           };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=TomCruise"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
NSError *error=nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString* aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;

if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
{
    allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:nil];
}

else{
    // allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:nil];
    allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:nil];

}

return allDataDictionary;
```

}

error message:

```
response {
errors =     (
            {
        code = 32;
        message = "Could not authenticate you.";
    }
);
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow it is a basic requirement to show some basic code of your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks @BobbyAxe . I have added the code here. I'm getting error code 32 with message could not authenticate you. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the twitter public tweet so you can go with the [TwitterKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/TwitterKit) by using `TWTRAPIClient` I don't know why you are going with native Oauth?

Below code will help you more use this code in `viewDidLoad` :)

```
TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (session) {
            if (!error && session) {

                NSLog(@"signed in with %@", [session userName]);

                TWTRAPIClient *APIClient = TWTRAPIClient.clientWithCurrentUser;
                TWTRUserTimelineDataSource *newArray =  [[TWTRUserTimelineDataSource alloc] initWithScreenName:@"TomCruise" APIClient:APIClient];
                [newArray loadPreviousTweetsBeforePosition:@"0" completion:^(NSArray<TWTRTweet *> * _Nullable tweets, TWTRTimelineCursor * _Nullable cursor, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    for (int count=0; count<tweets.count; count++) {
                        NSLog(@"tweet text is == \n%@",[tweets[count] text]); //You can use TWTRWEET Properties here
                    }
                }];

            }
            else if (error) {

                NSString *userID = [[[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] session] userID];
                if(userID){
                    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] logOutUserID:userID];
                }
            }
            else {

                NSString *userID = [[[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] session] userID];

                if(userID){
                    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] logOutUserID:userID];
                }
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@" dfdfhfgh error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
    logInButton.center = self.view.center;

    [logInButton layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.view addSubview:logInButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to show what you have tried and which code is not working. You cannot ask for code in this site.
2. As for OAuth, you just need to install TwitterKit framework (there is also Cocoapod for it, or you can manual install), and follow the instructions here: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Log-In-With-Twitter

Good luck.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check where I'm mistaking.